# array of marker layers is not being deleted from leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I am using the following code to delete circles from the map before adding new circles depending on location.

```
if(markers.length>0)
    {
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        map.removeLayer(markers[i]);
    }
    }

var lat,lon;
var road;
var detector;
//var svg=d3.select("#map").append("svg");
data.forEach(function(d)
        {
    lat=d.lat;
    lon=d.lon;
    road=d.road;
    detector=d.detectorid;
    markers.push((new L.circle([lat, lon], 500, {
        color: 'yellow',
        fillColor: '#f0f',
        fillOpacity: 0.5
    })).bindPopup("Road Name:"+road+"<br>Detector ID: "+detector))

        });
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    map.addLayer(markers[i]);
}
map.setView([lat, lon],13);
map.dragging.enable();
```

But the previous circles are not being added. New circles are being added side by side the old circles are kept. How can I remove the previous circles?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You should post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows an example.

Comment: Hi,I have a function. I am calling that function from a change of combobox. If I change the combox selection then the map should show few locations in selected area in the combobox. So when i change my selection in the combobox then the locations in map map should be updated removing previous locations

Comment: What function? I don't see a function? You should post all the relevant code if you want some decent answers

Comment: this whole code is inside the function function updateMap(data){...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old markers are getting redrawn because you're not emptying the marker array after you clear the layers on the map. After your first `if` statement you need to empty markers variable by setting `markers = []`. This way, when `marker.push` gets called in your forEach loop, their getting added to a new array without the old circles.